# Check state of checkboxes in an array - runtime error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object

I want to run one block of code when any of the 197 checkboxes on the form are clicked. I have all of the checkboxes in an array which I used to check the availability of each seat on the forms load (this program is a seat booking system). Each seat is a checkbox displayed as a button, and I would like the "Seats selected" label to show the seat selected once it has been checked. I used the same array in the code below to check whether they were checked, and if they were the label would be updated. The code below is giving me an error described as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I click one of the checkboxes. I'm not sure why this is and I can't really find a solution. I am only coding the first three checkboxes at the moment, just to see if it works. Ideally I would like to list all 197 checkboxes as handles to this procedure, so when any are clicked every seats checkstate will be checked.

If anyone has a solution that would be great! Thanks.

```
Public Class frmSeatPlan

Dim seat(11, 20) As Control

Private Sub A1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles A1.CheckedChanged, A2.CheckedChanged, A3.CheckedChanged

    seat(1, 1) = A1
    seat(1, 2) = A2
    seat(1, 3) = A3

    For y = 1 To 1
        For x = 1 To 3
            Dim seat(y, x) As CheckBox
            If seat(y, x).Checked = True Then
                selectedSeats = selectedSeats & seat(y, x).Name & ", "
                MsgBox(selectedSeats)
                lblSelected.Text = selectedSeats
            End If
        Next x
    Next y



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to write handles clause 197 times? Can you be sure by the time you finished you did not make a mistake? What if you add a seat #198 between #156 and #157 - how would you go around it? You are gradually planning a maintenance nightmare for yourself. Instead, you should bind events in code, where you would also create those checkboxes. This way you will never have the problem you were getting.

```
For y = 1 to 3
  For x = 1 to 3
    Dim chk As New CheckBox
    'set positioning on the screen
    chk.X = x
    chk.Y = y
    AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf Any_CheckedChanged
  Next
Next
```

Ideally, you will not need your array as well, i.e. `seat(y, x)`, because every seat can be assigned X and Y when they are created and pass those as event arguments (so you probably will need a custom event).